# Не перехватываются сообщения

Tags: битрикс

Проект реализован на 1с-Битриксе! 
Есть форма посыла сообщений почты через стандартные компоненты, а именно через iblock.element.add.formю.  Форма называется:

```
<form class="_iblock_add_" name="iblock_add"...
```

Прямо перед ней сделал обращение:

```
$('#iblock_submit').click(function(){
      console.log('Нельзя его остановить никак!');
      return false;
  });
```

Пояснение: iblock_submit - кнопка субмита для отправки сообщений формы.

Альтернативно пробовал также выполнить такой код:

```
$('._iblock_add_').submit(function(){
      console.log('Нельзя его остановить никак!');
      return false;
  });
```

Как в 1с-Битриксе осуществить выполнение определенных действий перед отправкой сообщений формы. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('._iblock_add_').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); //отмена события
      console.log('делаю что хочу!');
      $('._iblock_add_').submit(); //отправка формы
  });
```

примерно как то так можно, исходя из твоего примера